# Fresh wordpress installation in sub-directory not accessible

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, directory

I install fresh installation of wordpress in my server sub-folder call `blog`.

So in the beginning I access the site `mydomain/blog` and it works perfectly.

But when I changed the `permalinks` settings to `Post name` option in the `settings`, all urls giving me 403 - forbidden error including frot-end.

And then I realize it is because of `.htaccess` file inside the `/blog` folder as bellow.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It was automatically create after I change the `permalinks` settings.
When I rename the `.htaccess` file to another name homepage is accessible and not others.

Does anybody have an idea to what should I do in order to get the things back in action.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding Options `+FollowSymLinks` to the top of the `.htaccess` file.

If that doesn't work, verify that the host has `AllowOverride` enabled. Verify what they have the `AllowOverride` set to.

`mod_rewrite` can be used to simulate a symbolic link. This is why mod_rewrite requires `FollowSymLinks` to be enabled, because it's a similar security thing. So if your host doesn't enable `FollowSymLinks`, and you try using `mod_rewrite`, you'll get the `403` error. Adding Options `+FollowSymLinks` will override it for your directory, allowing `mod_rewrite` to work.

But, if you have this problem and you add Options `+FollowSymLinks` and then get a `500` error instead, then your host is disallowing the use of the Options directive in `.htaccess` files, and there's little you can do but complain to them.

copied from : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/403-forbidden-after-enabling-permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the rewrite module is enabled?

Type:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

If you are on Linux or equivalent for your platform/setup. You can also try:

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

and look for the rewrite module in there?